# Eclipse Kepler doesn't allow me to install plugins

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Just last week I installed egit with the plugin manager in eclipse (K). Now, I wanted to install ObjectAid. Only, none of my repositories (even the standard ones) are able to connect.

```
"Could not find... url"
```

I already went to preferences->install/update-> reloaded the urls, but then I get an error as well:

```
Unable to read repository at http://download.eclipse.org/tools/cdt/releases/kepler/content.xml.
Unable to read repository at http://download.eclipse.org/tools/cdt/releases/kepler/content.xml.
Failure initializing default SSL context
```

I also looked at the network settings, changed "native" to "direct", to no avail.

I know I can just download the plugin and install it manually, but that is cumbersome, I would like the network install to work.

Could it be some sort of "locked" file somewhere?

### Update

My git push is also not working (local commit works fine). This is probably related. Strange that the internal browser works though.

### Error log

```
!MESSAGE Provisioning exception
!STACK 1
org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core.ProvisionException: Unable to read repository at http://archive.eclipse.org/tools/cdt/releases/kepler/content.xml.
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.CacheManager.createCache(CacheManager.java:192)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.SimpleMetadataRepositoryFactory.getLocalFile(SimpleMetadataRepositoryFactory.java:66)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.SimpleMetadataRepositoryFactory.load(SimpleMetadataRepositoryFactory.java:88)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.factoryLoad(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:57)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.loadRepository(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:768)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.loadRepository(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:668)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.loadRepository(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:96)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.loadRepository(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:92)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui.LoadMetadataRepositoryJob.doLoad(LoadMetadataRepositoryJob.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui.LoadMetadataRepositoryJob.runModal(LoadMetadataRepositoryJob.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.ui.sdk.PreloadingRepositoryHandler$2.runModal(PreloadingRepositoryHandler.java:83)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.p2.operations.ProvisioningJob.run(ProvisioningJob.java:177)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failure initializing default SSL context
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.createDefaultSSLContext(SSLSocketFactory.java:211)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.<init>(SSLSocketFactory.java:333)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(SSLSocketFactory.java:165)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.SchemeRegistryFactory.createDefault(SchemeRegistryFactory.java:45)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.createClientConnectionManager(AbstractHttpClient.java:294)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.getConnectionManager(AbstractHttpClient.java:445)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.createHttpContext(AbstractHttpClient.java:274)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:797)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:754)
    at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient4.HttpClientFileSystemBrowser.runRequest(HttpClientFileSystemBrowser.java:263)
    at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.browse.AbstractFileSystemBrowser$DirectoryJob.run(AbstractFileSystemBrowser.java:69)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.security.KeyStoreException: problem accessing trust storejava.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format
    at sun.security.ssl.TrustManagerFactoryImpl.engineInit(TrustManagerFactoryImpl.java:75)
    at javax.net.ssl.TrustManagerFactory.init(TrustManagerFactory.java:250)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.createSSLContext(SSLSocketFactory.java:190)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.createDefaultSSLContext(SSLSocketFactory.java:209)
    ... 11 more
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.transport.ecf 4 1002 2013-10-10 10:31:15.936
!MESSAGE Unable to read repository at http://archive.eclipse.org/tools/cdt/releases/kepler/content.xml.
!STACK 0
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failure initializing default SSL context
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.createDefaultSSLContext(SSLSocketFactory.java:211)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.<init>(SSLSocketFactory.java:333)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(SSLSocketFactory.java:165)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.SchemeRegistryFactory.createDefault(SchemeRegistryFactory.java:45)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.createClientConnectionManager(AbstractHttpClient.java:294)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.getConnectionManager(AbstractHttpClient.java:445)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.createHttpContext(AbstractHttpClient.java:274)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:797)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:754)
    at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient4.HttpClientFileSystemBrowser.runRequest(HttpClientFileSystemBrowser.java:263)
    at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.browse.AbstractFileSystemBrowser$DirectoryJob.run(AbstractFileSystemBrowser.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
Caused by: java.security.KeyStoreException: problem accessing trust storejava.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format
    at sun.security.ssl.TrustManagerFactoryImpl.engineInit(TrustManagerFactoryImpl.java:75)
    at javax.net.ssl.TrustManagerFactory.init(TrustManagerFactory.java:250)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.createSSLContext(SSLSocketFactory.java:190)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.createDefaultSSLContext(SSLSocketFactory.java:209)
    ... 11 more

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui 4 0 2013-10-10 10:31:22.730
!MESSAGE Unable to read repository at http://download.eclipse.org/releases/kepler/content.xml.
!STACK 1
org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core.ProvisionException: Unable to read repository at http://download.eclipse.org/releases/kepler/content.xml.
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.CacheManager.createCache(CacheManager.java:192)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.SimpleMetadataRepositoryFactory.getLocalFile(SimpleMetadataRepositoryFactory.java:66)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.SimpleMetadataRepositoryFactory.load(SimpleMetadataRepositoryFactory.java:88)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.factoryLoad(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:57)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.loadRepository(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:768)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.loadRepository(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:668)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.loadRepository(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:96)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.loadRepository(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:92)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui.ProvisioningUI.loadMetadataRepository(ProvisioningUI.java:439)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.ui.model.MetadataRepositoryElement.getMetadataRepository(MetadataRepositoryElement.java:120)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.ui.model.MetadataRepositoryElement.fetchChildren(MetadataRepositoryElement.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.ui.model.RemoteQueriedElement.fetchDeferredChildren(RemoteQueriedElement.java:34)
    at org.eclipse.ui.progress.DeferredTreeContentManager$1.run(DeferredTreeContentManager.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failure initializing default SSL context
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.createDefaultSSLContext(SSLSocketFactory.java:211)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.<init>(SSLSocketFactory.java:333)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(SSLSocketFactory.java:165)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.SchemeRegistryFactory.createDefault(SchemeRegistryFactory.java:45)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.createClientConnectionManager(AbstractHttpClient.java:294)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.getConnectionManager(AbstractHttpClient.java:445)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.createHttpContext(AbstractHttpClient.java:274)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:797)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:754)
    at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient4.HttpClientFileSystemBrowser.runRequest(HttpClientFileSystemBrowser.java:263)
    at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.browse.AbstractFileSystemBrowser$DirectoryJob.run(AbstractFileSystemBrowser.java:69)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.security.KeyStoreException: problem accessing trust storejava.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format
    at sun.security.ssl.TrustManagerFactoryImpl.engineInit(TrustManagerFactoryImpl.java:75)
    at javax.net.ssl.TrustManagerFactory.init(TrustManagerFactory.java:250)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.createSSLContext(SSLSocketFactory.java:190)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.createDefaultSSLContext(SSLSocketFactory.java:209)
    ... 11 more
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.transport.ecf 4 1002 2013-10-10 10:31:22.730
!MESSAGE Unable to read repository at http://download.eclipse.org/releases/kepler/content.xml.
!STACK 0
```

Could there be a problem with the fact that I also have eclipse juno on this computer? I run it with a different workspace though.

Comment: Which OS are you using.. ?

Comment: Yes it is 64 bit and I am using: eclipse-standard-kepler-R-linux-gtk-x86_64

Comment: Look in the Error Log view or the .log file in the .metadata to see if there is a more detailed error.

Comment: I have added the error log info to the question.

Comment: Could there be a problem with the fact that I also have eclipse juno on this computer? I run it with a different workspace though.

Comment: Looking at the end of your log: "storejava.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format"... Perhaps, your trusted certificates file got corrupted. Delete it (with a backup if you prefer) to verify it.

Comment: I am unure how to delete te certificates, where can I find them?

Comment: Oh found the solution. Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a `bug in open jdk 1.7` from the suse repos. So I installed the jdk 1.7 rpm which is offered by Oracle. Be sure that your **eclipse points to the right java version**

```
(Window >> Preferences >> Java >> Installed JRE).
```

Comment: Fixed mine :) - was on 1.7 changed to 1.6 and it worked!

Answer (score 24):

Fantastic! I simply appended the port number 80 to the URL and it works for me!
http://download.eclipse.org:80/releases/kepler

Comment: I recently installed Kepler on Ubuntu 10.4 LTS and had the same problem. There was no enterprise proxy involved. To change the URL as mentioned above, go to 
`Window -> Preferences -> Install/Update -> Available Software Sites` and under the entry "Kepler" edit `http://download.eclipse.org/releases/kepler` to `http://download.eclipse.org:80/releases/kepler`. That did the trick for me.

Comment: Using Mars, getting the same error as described above, this solution also worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

Possible Solutions:

- Try **starting eclipse with** the following argument and add it to `eclipse.ini` :

  `-vmargs -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true`
- Check the **port and proxy settings** under

  `Window -> Preferences -> General -> Network Connections`

You need to make sure that whatever outgoing port(s) your organization allows, you're using one of those, and enter the settings for any proxy your organization requires. Change the port to a usable port like 80

Comment: Starting eclipse with the top arguments makes no change. As for the proxy, I don't use a proxy, it doesn't work in the office or at home. It used to work though, stopped after installing egit.

Comment: Did you find a solution to the problem..?

Comment: No, was actually just trying to install the cdt plugin. Still the same problem.

Comment: I tried my old eclipse juno that was still somewhere in a folder, it has the same problem. Also installed a new eclipse from the repo from suse, same thing. Updated my openjdk. Still the same prob. Getting problematic, since I want to install cdt, but it needs dependancies etc and it's a hassle to look them up manually

Comment: Was a different reason in the end, but might as well give somebody the reputation. Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same symptoms, on Fedora.  Installing plugins worked once, then every source failed on the next attempt.

I saw on a forum post to try adding `-clean` to eclipse on the command line.  Starting with `eclipse -clean` put me into a mode where I could not install any software, but after a quit and starting eclipse normally, I could install plugins again without any complaints.

Looking around, this flag clears out a bunch internal caches in eclipse. As this was only my second time running eclipse, I wonder if I just had bad luck or if it's typically this shaky.

Answer (score 0):

My antivirus firewall was causing this problem.

After I disabled the firewall of my antivirus, I am able to fetch child of http://download.eclipse.org/releases/mars