# Provisioning Exception for Eclipse Kepler AngularJS tools

Tags: java, eclipse, angularjs, installation, provisioning

I am having great difficulty installing these AngularJS plugins for Eclipse. The 'Install new software' dialog tells me that it 'could not find' the update site, and the 'No repository found at [url]' exception is raised.

The update site is http://oss.opensagres.fr/angularjs-eclipse/0.2.0/ . I can navigate to this page just fine on my browser and see the content.jar, artifacts.jar, etc. Additionally, other update sites seem to work fine, the problem seems specific to this repository. The same error occurs in earlier versions of Eclipse on this computer, and the error does *not* occur on other computers.

Things I have tried: Basically every solution from this question: [Eclipse Kepler doesn't allow me to install plugins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19290108/eclipse-kepler-doesnt-allow-me-to-install-plugins)

- Proxy settings seem correct
- Tried specifying the port in the URL
- Made sure eclipse is pointing at the right JRE

I have also tried variations on the solution provided here for a manual install:
http://prabhugs.wordpress.com/2014/01/03/angularjs-in-eclipse-ide/

But the maven tycho plugin download gives me checksum fails and 'invalid extension descriptor' errors. (Probably another problem entirely).

Comment: Today version is 0.3.0. Have you retried to install with http://oss.opensagres.fr/angularjs-eclipse/0.3.0/? If it doesn't work, have you tried to install AngularJS Eclipse with marketplace?

Comment: Just tried again, with the update site and the marketplace, same error with both of them. I'm pretty convinced now that the problem lies with the corporate firewall here, in which case there's nothing to do but appeal to the IT helpdesk. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Indeed, I think it's a problem with your corporate firewall, because I have tested to install it and it work's for me. Sorry I cannot help you more.